# SQL Server 2008 r2: TSQL IIF Query not recognized

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, iif

I'm trying to use `IIF` for the first time instead of a `CASE` and SQL Server is throwing this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near '>'.

My code:

```
DECLARE @lDate date = CONVERT(date,GETDATE());
DECLARE @lMonth int = MONTH(@lDate);
DECLARE @lDay int = DAY(@lDate);

DECLARE @lPeriodStart date, @lPeriodEnd date, @lPayPeriod int, @lCutOffDay int = 14;

--there are 24 pay periods find which one
SET @lPayPeriod = @lMonth * 2 - IIF(@lDay > @lCutOffDay, 0, 1);

SELECT @lPayPeriod
```

I don't understand how this is different from the guidelines from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IIF` was introduced in SQL Server 2012. As you've tagged your question with SQL Server 2008 I'd say that is the source of the problem.

Your syntax is valid and the code would work in a newer version.

Comment: Not being a native English speaker I'm not sure if `was` is the correct tense in the first sentence, or if if should be `were`. Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: "was" is correct here. "were" would be appropriate when you speak of plural things.  "IIF was introduced in SS 2012" "IIF and COLUMNSTORE were introduced in SS 2012"

Comment: @DaveMarkle Thanks for clarifying it for me.